# Show multiple check box in codeigniter from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my database i have a field called ARG_1.
i contains Home,Work,Work2

Now i fetch this from database.

And I want to show this three as separate checkbox. Like this:

```
input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option One'>Home<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>Work<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Three'>Work2
```

How to do this?

I did this but didnt work:

```
$params = $this->model->get();    
foreach($params as $value) $new_val = explode(',',$value->arg_1); 
            {
                echo form_checkbox($new_val);
            }
```

Comment: What you are going to do in this function form_checkbox($new_val);  ?

Comment: thats codeigniter way of displaying the checkbox,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your **model**

Write this query

```
public function yourMethodName(){
    $this->db->select('ARG_1');
    $q=$this->db->get('your-table-name');
    return $q->result();
}
```

and on **controller**
first load your model and then call model method which have you made and send  data to your view page

like this...

```
$this->load->model('your-model-name'); # Load model
$data['details']=$this->your-model-name->yourMethodName(); # Load Model Method
$this->load->view('your-view-page-name',$data); #Load your view page
```

and finally on **View** page

```
foreach($details as $rows){

     $exp_arr=explode(',',$rows->ARG_1); # convert ARG_1 string value into array
     for($i=0;$i<count($exp_arr);$i++){

          echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>".$exp_arr[$i]."<br>";
     }

}
```

Hope this code will help you

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: I get this error and for model i am select * from table instead of just ARG1

Comment: this works i copied your code so it showed me error i had to change ARG_1 to arg_1

Answer (score 0):

Try this One of the simple way

```
$sno=1;
$i=0;
for($sno;$sno<=$params->num_rows();$sno++)
{
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]" id="checkboxvar" value="<?php echo $params[$i]->check_box_value; ?>">';
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Comment: model->get();   gives what?

Comment: ok use $params=$this->db->get->('db_table'); instead of calling model $params = $this->model->get();